# easy_install on windows , refusing to find ANY packages - firewall?

Tags: python, easy-install

I am having a problem with easy_install. Firstly, I have the easy_install package on a python distribution (2.7) that is part of UCSF chimera, a python based molecular visualisation software. Everything about this python distribution is the same as the official 2.7, apart from the fact that it has additional elements specific for Chimera.

My easy_install appears to not like searching the repositories! It constantly crashes out, however the same search on another machine works fine. So, I have reason to suspect something is blocking the easy_install from accessing the repositories on the previous machine. Is there anything I can try to test the waters?

I can get this error :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510
: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol --       Some packages may not be found!
 Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
 Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510:       error:1
 40770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol -- Some packages ma
y not be found!
No local packages or download links found for numpy
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy')
```

---

I tried using pip : but I get a similar error hinting at something to do with the connectivity. However, I know that the connection is fine, as another computer on the same internet with the same connectivity settings works fine.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Chimera 1.10.1\bin\Lib\site-packages>pip install biskit
Collecting biskit
C:\Program Files (x86)\Chimera 1.10.1\bin\lib\site-packages\pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg\
pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning:
A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configurin
g SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more info
rmation, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecurepla
tformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
C:\Program Files (x86)\Chimera 1.10.1\bin\lib\site-packages\pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg\
pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning:
A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configurin
g SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more info
rmation, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecurepla
tformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement biskit (from versions:
 )
No matching distribution found for biskit
C:\Program Files (x86)\Chimera 1.10.1\bin\lib\site-packages\pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg\
pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning:
A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configurin
g SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more info
rmation, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecurepla
tformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning

C:\Program Files (x86)\Chimera 1.10.1\bin\Lib\site-packages>^A

C:\Program Files (x86)\Chimera 1.10.1\bin\Lib\site-packages>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using pip instead?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? Can you post what you tried and did not try and what you know about your network ?

Comment: I am not on a proxy, because another computer on the same internet connection, with the same settings works perfectly well. I have resigned to using the other computer now, but I am still desperately trying to find out the reason for this. It appears it is urllib3 and it failure to verify SSL certificaticate because of an older version of Python beign used. However, this is the version I have to use and it is obviously working on another computer despite the error. Hard to see where this is failing.